# How can I display data in List view using MVVM in Xamain?

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin

How can I display data in List view using MVVM in Xamain?
The REST data is coming as a dictionary.
How to im
The Rest API data is:

```
{
"ResponseCode": 1,
"ResponseMessage": "Registers exist.",
"Data": {
    "777": {
        "57": {
            "register_name": "Vehicles..",
            "custom_fields": "{\"customFields\":[{\"name\":\"Kms\",\"type\":\"TextSingle\",\"required\":\"false\"},{\"name\":\"Date\",\"type\":\"Date\",\"required\":\"false\"},{\"name\":\"New\",\"type\":\"CustomField\",\"required\":\"false\",\"value\":\"19\"},{\"name\":\"New car?\",\"type\":\"CustomField\",\"required\":\"false\",\"value\":\"63\"},{\"name\":\"Test drive\",\"type\":\"CustomField\",\"required\":\"false\",\"value\":\"1\"},{\"name\":\"Not New \",\"type\":\"CustomField\",\"required\":\"false\",\"value\":\"2\"},{\"name\":\"Multiline Field\",\"type\":\"TextMulti\",\"required\":\"false\"},{\"name\":\"test\",\"type\":\"TextMulti\",\"required\":\"false\"},{\"name\":\"test\",\"type\":\"TextSingle\",\"required\":\"false\"},{\"name\":\"test\",\"type\":\"TextMulti\",\"required\":\"false\"}]}",
            "no_of_records": 18,
            "no_of_tasks": 18
        },
        "139": {
            "register_name": "Lease on buildings",
            "custom_fields": "{\"customFields\":[{\"name\":\"fire extinguisher checks\",\"type\":\"TextSingle\",\"required\":\"false\"}]}",
            "no_of_records": 18,
            "no_of_tasks": 13
        },
        "179": {
            "register_name": "Monthly Newsletters",
            "custom_fields": "",
            "no_of_records": 4,
            "no_of_tasks": 2
        },
        "184": {
            "register_name": "Gifts and Donations Register",
            "custom_fields": "{\"customFields\":[{\"name\":\"Gifts\",\"type\":\"TextSingle\",\"required\":\"false\"},{\"name\":\"Date of receipt\",\"type\":\"Date\",\"required\":\"false\"}]}",
            "no_of_records": 5,
            "no_of_tasks": 2
        },
        "258": {
            "register_name": "IT Security",
            "custom_fields": "{\"customFields\":[{\"name\":\"Priority\",\"type\":\"CustomField\",\"required\":\"true\",\"value\":\"89\"},{\"name\":\"Select\",\"type\":\"CustomField\",\"required\":\"false\",\"value\":\"63\"},{\"name\":\"Essay \",\"type\":\"TextMulti\",\"required\":\"false\"}]}",
            "no_of_records": 5,
            "no_of_tasks": 2
        },
        "262": {
            "register_name": "Annual return",
            "custom_fields": "{\"customFields\":[{\"name\":\"Disclosure of interests for the return period from\",\"type\":\"Date\",\"required\":\"false\"},{\"name\":\"To\",\"type\":\"Date\",\"required\":\"false\"},{\"name\":\"Real property - Address\",\"type\":\"TextSingle\",\"required\":\"false\"},{\"name\":\"Nature of interest\",\"type\":\"TextSingle\",\"required\":\"false\"},{\"name\":\"Income sources - Description of the occupation\",\"type\":\"TextMulti\",\"required\":\"false\"},{\"name\":\"Name and address of the employer\",\"type\":\"TextSingle\",\"required\":\"false\"},{\"name\":\"Description of the office held\",\"type\":\"TextSingle\",\"required\":\"false\"},{\"name\":\"Name of the partnership\",\"type\":\"TextSingle\",\"required\":\"false\"},{\"name\":\"Income from Trust - Name of the trust\",\"type\":\"TextSingle\",\"required\":\"false\"},{\"name\":\"Name and address of the settlor\",\"type\":\"TextSingle\",\"required\":\"false\"},{\"name\":\"Name and address of the trustee\",\"type\":\"TextSingle\",\"required\":\"false\"},{\"name\":\"Sources of other income- Identify of persons\",\"type\":\"TextMulti\",\"required\":\"false\"},{\"name\":\"Describe circumstances \",\"type\":\"TextMulti\",\"required\":\"false\"}]}",
            "no_of_records": 2,
            "no_of_tasks": 0
        },
        "402": {
            "register_name": "Test Register",
            "custom_fields": "{\"customFields\":[{\"name\":\"Test field\",\"type\":\"TextSingle\",\"required\":\"false\"}]}",
            "no_of_records": 5,
            "no_of_tasks": 1
        },
        "492": {
            "register_name": "test reg",
            "custom_fields": "{\"customFields\":[{\"name\":\"test\",\"type\":\"TextSingle\",\"required\":\"true\"},{\"name\":\"test date\",\"type\":\"Date\",\"required\":\"false\"}]}",
            "no_of_records": 2,
            "no_of_tasks": 0
        }
    }
}
```

}

The class format is:

```
public class Root
        {
            public string ResponseCode { get; set; }
            public string ResponseMessage { get; set; }
            public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<int, RegisterData>> Data { get; set;}        
        }

        public class RegisterData
        {
            [JsonProperty("register_name")]
            public string RegisterName { get; set; }

           [JsonProperty("custom_fields")]
            public string CustomFields { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("no_of_records")]
            public int RecordsCount { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("no_of_tasks")]
            public int TasksCount { get; set; }
        }
```

How can I display data of RegisterData class in a ListView?
**The data to be displayed in List View is :
Register name:
No_of records
no of tasks
and record id: as the dictionary key.**

Comment: I'd suggest starting by using a LINQ query (or something) to unpack your data into a much flatter format, like just a `List<RegisterData>`

Answer (score 0):

According to your gson, you can try to use  [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) Nuget ,for example:

```
namespace QuickType
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class Welcome
    {
        [JsonProperty("ResponseCode")]
        public long ResponseCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ResponseMessage")]
        public string ResponseMessage { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Data")]
        public Data Data { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("777")]
        public Dictionary<string, The777> The777 { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class The777
    {
        [JsonProperty("register_name")]
        public string RegisterName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("custom_fields")]
        public string CustomFields { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("no_of_records")]
        public long NoOfRecords { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("no_of_tasks")]
        public long NoOfTasks { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Welcome
    {
        public static Welcome FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Welcome>(json, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this Welcome self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, QuickType.Converter.Settings);
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters =
            {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }
}
```

For more details, you can check: https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp

Note: you can just copy your json string to the left part of above link, then it will convert the json into relative data models.After that you can display these models normally.